# SQL: Number of occurrences grouped by frequency

Tags: sql-server

It's not clear the exact statement for me to use here. I want to know how many times certain occurrences happen in the table when the value is A. So for some sample data:

```
user | value 
1    |  A  
1    |  A 
1    |  B 
4    |  A 
4    |  A 
4    |  B 
5    |  A 
5    |  A 
5    |  A
```

Would result in:

```
Occurrence  Frequency
1           0
2           2
3           1
```

Which reads as: there are 0 users that have 1 value A. There are 2 users that have two value A etc.

I feel like I should use a group by and a count(*) by not clear to me how to construct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the occurrences even for `0` frequencies, you need a recursive `cte` which return all occurrences from 1 to the max number of occurrences.
Then you join this `cte` with a `LEFT` join to a query that aggregates on the table and aggregate once more to get the frequencies:

```
with 
  cte as (
    select count(*) counter
    from tablename
    where value = 'A'
    group by [user]
  ),
  top_counter as (select max(counter) counter from cte),
  occurrences as (
    select 1 occurrence
    union all
    select occurrence + 1
    from occurrences
    where occurrence < (select counter from top_counter)
  )
select o.occurrence, count(c.counter) frequency
from occurrences o left join cte c
on c.counter = o.occurrence
group by o.occurrence
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65b088e7e1935feeea413f50e51c28ca).
Results:

```
> occurrence | frequency
> ---------: | --------:
>          1 |         0
>          2 |         2
>          3 |         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You do use `COUNT`, just 2 of them:

```sql
WITH Counts AS(
    SELECT V.[User],
           COUNT([Value]) AS Frequency
    FROM (VALUES(1,'A'),  
                (1,'A'), 
                (1,'B'), 
                (4,'A'), 
                (4,'A'), 
                (4,'B'), 
                (5,'A'), 
                (5,'A'), 
                (5,'A'))V([User],[Value]) --USER is a reserved keyword and should not be used for object names
    WHERE V.[Value] = 'A'
    GROUP BY V.[user])
SELECT V.I,
       COUNT(C.Frequency) AS Frequecy
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3))V(I)
     LEFT JOIN Counts C ON V.I = C.Frequency
GROUP BY V.I;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

```
with cte as (
    select * from (values
        (1, 'A'),  
        (1, 'A'), 
        (1, 'B'), 
        (4, 'A'), 
        (4, 'A'), 
        (4, 'B'), 
        (5, 'A'), 
        (5, 'A'),
        (5, 'A') 
    ) as x([User], [Value])
)
select c, count(*)
from (
    select [User], count(*) as c
    from cte
    where [Value] = 'A'
    group by [User]
) as s
group by c;
```

The common table expression isn't important here - it's just setting up your test data.

What you're after is an aggregation of aggretations. That is, the first level aggregate is a "count of value by user". But then you're going to get a "count of (count of value by user) by (that count)". Note, my set doesn't produce the "0 users that have 1 value A". Nor does it produce "0 users that have 17 value A". If it's important that it produce certain negative results, you'll need a list of which ones you care about and join that list with this set of results with an outer join.